# Django: Multi Tenancy : Override Tenant Context

Tags: python, multi-tenant, django-tenants

I have overridden `django_tenants.utils.tenant_context` to activate a timezone specific to the tenant.

`class NewTenantContext(tenant_context): ...`

I can use the new context like this

`with ALSTenantContext(tenant): ...`

All this works fine for a specific process to start for a tenant.

But how do I make sure `NewTenantContext` is used when tenant is set from Admin or API?

Comment: I have overridden django_tenants.utils.tenant_context to implement tenant specific time zone.  
Is there any other mechanism to implement the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to resolve this by overriding middleware  django_tenants.middleware.TenantMainMiddleware